Does this equality imply choice?
Does ZF + "For all infinite sets $A$, there is a bijection between $A^3$ and $A^2$" imply AC?
Let $\aleph(A)$ be the least ordinal that does not inject into $A$.
I know $|A+\aleph(A)|=|A\times\aleph(A)|$ implies $A$ can be well ordered.
I got
\begin{align}&|(A+\aleph(A))^2|\\
=&|(A+\aleph(A))^3|\\
=&|A^3+3\times A^2\times\aleph(A)+3\times A\times\aleph(A)^2+\aleph(A)^3|\\
=&|A^2+A^2\times\aleph(A)+A\times\aleph(A)+\aleph(A)|\\
\le&|4\times A^2\times\aleph(A)|\\
=&|A^2\times\aleph(A)|\\
\le&|A^2+A^2\times\aleph(A)+A\times\aleph(A)+\aleph(A)|\end{align}
Since $|\aleph(A)|=|\aleph(A)^2|$, $|(A+\aleph(A))^2|=|A^2\times\aleph(A)|=|A^2\times\aleph(A)^2|=|(A\times\aleph(A))^2|$. This is almost what I need. But I don't know if this approach will work or if the statement I am trying to prove is even true.

I was able to prove $|A^2\times \mu| = |A^2|$ for all $\mu<\aleph(A)$, and with some difficulty $|A^2\times \aleph(A)| = |A\times \aleph(A)|$ for all infinite $A$. I couldn't find a way to fit either of these into any of the usual proofs of Choice. My original instinct was that this won't imply Choice, but maybe my results will help someone.

Sorry, I'm working on trying to fix the answer, but I'm traveling and my internet access is somewhat intermittent.
